# How do you access an image file in paragraphs module from php?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, paragraphs

I can't seems to be able to access to a image field in a paragraphs module.

I can access to other fields value but not the image field.

```
          $paragraph = Paragraph::load($team_type['target_id']);
          $new_obj->title = $paragraph->field_title->value;      
          $new_obj->age = $paragraph->field_age->value;
          $new_obj->info = $paragraph->field_about_info->value;
          $new_obj->link = $paragraph->field_link_to_page->value;

          $new_obj->logo = $paragraph->field_logo_image->value;
```

The **field_logo_image** doesn't have anything in it.  I did a google search but still can't able to find a solution.

I did checked the image field unique name and it's correct.

My question is, how do you access to an image field in Drupal 8 paragraphs module from your custom module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for but i was able to get the image style url doing this.

```
      $paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph_image[0]['target_id']);
      $ogPara = $paragraph->get('field_image')->entity->uri->value;
      $style = ImageStyle::load('list_thumbnail_square_100x100');
      $url = $style->buildUrl($ogPara);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you specified "from php" but accessing those values from paragraph template can be also helpful to someone. I.e. if paragraph has image field called "field_image" and you want to print image in "image_style_name" style you can do it from paragraph template like this:

```
<img
        alt="{{ content.field_image['0']['#item'].alt }}"
        title="{{ content.field_image['0']['#item'].alt }}"
        src="{{ content.field_image['0']['#item'].entity.uri.value|change_image_style('image_style_name') }}" >
```